# Retrieve HTML from Web.Config in Code-Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, html-email

**Web.Config:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="html1" value="This is &lt;br /&gt; HTML email"/>
</appSettings>
```

I'm trying to generate HTML formatted email. Prior to putting data in Web.Config I had both text and HTML emails formatted correctly.

**In code-behind:**

```
StringBuilder emailMessageString = new StringBuilder();
emailMessageString.Append(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["html1"].ToString());
```

**Output in HTML email:**

This is <br /> HTML email

**Expected output in HTML email:**

This is

HTML email

**UPDATE - 02-19-2015**

It looks like code I wrote to generate HTML email is not working correctly and had previously posted the code in this question (in my own answer). Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong as it looks like only the text emails are working:

[Correct Syntax for Generating HTML Email using AlternateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391070/correct-syntax-for-generating-html-email-using-alternateview)

Comment: I have a feeling it's because you are storing HTML in XML format. Do you need to un-XML the value before outputting the HTML?

Comment: Not sure how you mean Jeremy - I tried combinations of &lt;/&gt; and &#60;/&#62 in conjunction with HtmlEncode() and HtmlDecode() calls and can't get it to play right. My understanding is that they are all strings in config section...

Comment: out of curiosity, can you output the raw html that is generated using both methods?

Comment: Could it be that you send plain text email instead of HTML ?

Comment: I think you guys are on to something - will update question shortly and show how I'm attempting to generate the html in email.

Comment: `web.config` seems like a bad place to store HTML. Put it in a .html file. Or even better, use [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) to generate your email bodies using Razor syntax, just like you would with an MVC page.

Comment: Sorry Mason, I refuse point blank to mix code and markup with Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to decode again. This should solve it -

```
var body = new StringBuilder();
body.Append(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["html1"]);
```

Also, ensure that you set **IsBodyHtml** to true.

```
var message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: Updating question with your suggestion Win; I think problem might be in way I'm generating HTML in email - will update again shortly when I can narrow it down, thx :)

Comment: The reason the HTML wasn't working was because I was stupidly trying to display output in a textbox :/

Answer (score 0):

Hello Brother you can use [Server.HtmlDecode(string s)](http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode)

see below code

```
StringBuilder emailMessageString = new StringBuilder();
emailMessageString.Append(Server.HtmlDecode(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["html1"].ToString()));
```